# How can I log the results of a series of TAP tests, while keeping the output to the user separate?

Tags: perl, logging, tap

I have a series of tests that I run through a Test::Harness. I'm quite happy with the level of verbosity that the tests have so far: the user knows the number of tests that ran and the number of tests that succeeded, and the overall results of the test:

```
/home/user/project/t/01.my_test.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=136, 15 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys + 13.84 cusr  0.55 csys = 14.42 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

However, **I would like to log the output of each test into a separate file that can be checked at a later date**. The regular output while running the test should still be the same (an aggregate), but the `test.log` (or however it is named) should have the information for the specific result for each test that run (hopefully including any additional parts of the output, like comments and such).

The closest I've got is capturing the entire output with `Capture::Tiny` and then processing it myself manually. But apart from this being cumbersome and error prone, the output is processed all as a whole, so while the tests are running there is nothing to show. I would like to avoid this.

I've looked at `TAP::Harness::Archive` as well, but I couldn't get it to run, so I'm not sure if it can be used for this.

What is the best way to do this?

### Edit

I'm implementing a pseudo package manager, and the tests I'm running are part of the installation process. When the packages get installed it is tested, and if the tests fail installation is aborted.

This is implemented right now as a `test` method for a `package` object. I thought that, since this would have to run on multiple different platforms, it was probably a better idea to do things within Perl, without having to call system commands (including `prove`), but I'm ready to change my ways.

This is how tests are being run right now:

```
use Path::Class;
my @tests;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
  push @tests, file($path, $file) if ($file =~ /\.t$/);
}
@tests = sort @tests;

# Run the tests
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new({
  failures  => 1,
  exec => [ 'myinterpreter' ],
});
my $aggregator = $harness->runtests(@tests);

if ($aggregator->all_passed) { return 1 } else { return 0 }
```

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to look why `TAP::Harness::Archive` isn't working? I've written an module which works together with it, which might be of use: `Archive::TAP::Convert`

Comment: Can you also show in your question how you are running the tests? Are you using `prove`?

Comment: I'll take a look at your module to see if I can get an idea of where I went wrong and report back.

Comment: `prove` is just a (very thin) wrapper around `App::Prove`. If you're trying to avoid system calls, you could use the module directly.

Comment: @MichaelCarman I think that's the way to go. I'll accept the answer by Boris since they both point to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your tests with the tool `prove`. It provides the option `-a` to archive each run in the TAP-Format. This can then be later processed, e.g. with `Archive::TAP::Convert`.

Here I run the tool in a module directory, where the code is in `lib` and the tests are in `t`:

```
prove -a tests.tgz -Ilib t/
```

The results are displayed to terminal and also captured in the file `tests.tgz`.

Maybe not exactly what you where looking for? But it works and is solid. You should use the tools, when they are already there.

**NOTE:** According to the comment from Michael Carman, "*prove is just a (very thin) wrapper around App::Prove. If you're trying to avoid system calls, you could use the module directly.*"

Comment: I'd prefer to keep things within Perl for this, but this is maybe the best way to do what I want. I'm all for using the appropriate tools, so maybe this is all a sign that I'm doing it wrong.